# can't find facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I created a HTML facebook app, which runs over an iframe using HTTPS.
I can go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and see the app listed.
I can click on the app to open its dashboard.
It says "This app is public and available to all users" yet I don't see it on the left side column of the main FB page. There is an old app there which I also don't see in my list of apps. I'm guessing that somehow I'm not in the right "spot" but I've never experienced something as confusing as the FB API.

Where is my app?

Comment: The left side column shows what you accessed frequently; you can also configure it in some ways. // I assume you’re talking about a canvas app here (resp. what is known as Facebook Web Games platform now), those apps can be reached under `https://apps.facebook.com/{yourappnamespacehere}`

Comment: The lift column are FB "tabs" that are always the same.

Comment: So a simple Page Tab app then ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up using is a thing called [Static HTML: iframe tabs](https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/)
It walks you through an easy step by step process where you link your web page into it and it shows up on the TABS on the left column of the page.